# install zf2 on xampp on windows 7 without zend skeleton

Tags: php, zend-framework2

is there any way to install zf2 using zf2 files only (please see the picture), without using zend skeleton or git ? (operating system:windows 7 32-bit, xampp-version:1.8.1)

-thanks.

[image]

Comment: u can always manually download the zf2 library and then properly set up your autoloader. This is basically the same as in ZF1. Though for your own comfort: get comfortable with composer and git - u wont have fun without those tools, trust me ;) dependencies will turn into a nightmare for u otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think Zend Framework 2.0 skeleton refers to all the group of files and directories that are essential to run the Zend app. You can collect/pick/copy all the necessary files from the zip and place/paste them in your add - on domain or virtually hosted directory and will work fine for you.